divergence in spherical co-ordinates.
so i was solving a problem where I needed to find the divergence of some vector V in spherical coordinate and this was how i tried to proceed, by doing how i used to do it in cartesian
and obviously my answer is not matching because the formula for divergence in this case is given by:
i do not understand the scaling that are being done here...why cant it be done like the way i was doing it.

You've been around for a while, you should use MathJax

Related

The tersest answer that should put you on the right track is that when you "dot" the "del" operator with the vector field you should use covariant differentiation to make the divergence independent of the chosen coordinate system. This leads to the Voss-Weyl formula and ultimately to the correct expression for the divergence.

As is thoroughly explained in the thread to which Sine of the Time linked, your mistake comes from the fact that the unit spherical vectors $\hat r, \hat \theta, \hat \phi$ are not constant. They point in different directions at different locations. So when applying $\nabla$, you have to also differentiate the unit vectors, not just their coefficients.
